# Make a list of 2x2 matrices from a list of vectors

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I want to make a list of four 2x2 matrices from this list

```
str(SC_sum)    
List of 4
 $ : Named num [1:4] 0.5927 0.2927 0.5977 0.0227
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "chisel" "disc" "field_cultivator" "moldboard"
 $ : Named num [1:4] 0.408 0.705 0.401 0.4
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "chisel" "disc" "field_cultivator" "moldboard"
 $ : Named num [1:4] 0.0758 0.1521 0.1028 0.0757
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "chisel" "disc" "field_cultivator" "moldboard"
 $ : Named num [1:4] 0.924 0.848 0.897 0.454
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "chisel" "disc" "field_cultivator" "moldboard"
```

with `lapply(SC_sum, "matrix", nrow = 2, byrow = T)`

I expect my `chisel` matrix to be `matrix(c(0.5926667, 0.4083333, 0.0758125, 0.9240000), nrow = 2, byrow = F)`, which is the first element in each of the four vectors in `SC_sum`, then `disc` matrix to be the combination of the second element in each vector in `SC_sum`, and so on.

My current `chisel` matrix is `matrix(c(0.59266667, 0.29266667, 0.59766667, 0.02266667), nrow = 2, byrow = F)` which is the rearrangement of the *first vector*. How do I change my code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? Here, `x` is taking the place of your `SC_sum`.

```r
x <- split(seq_len(16), gl(4, 4))
x <- lapply(x, `names<-`, letters[1:4])
x
```

```
$`1`
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 

$`2`
a b c d 
5 6 7 8 

$`3`
 a  b  c  d 
 9 10 11 12 

$`4`
 a  b  c  d 
13 14 15 16
```

```r
m <- matrix(unlist(x), nrow = length(x[[1]]), ncol = length(x), 
            dimnames = list(names(x[[1]]), NULL))
m
```

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    1    5    9   13
b    2    6   10   14
c    3    7   11   15
d    4    8   12   16
```

```r
l <- apply(m, 1, matrix, ncol = 2, simplify = FALSE)
l
```

```
$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    5   13

$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   10
[2,]    6   14

$c
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   11
[2,]    7   15

$d
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   12
[2,]    8   16
```

If you really want to use `lapply` and not `apply`, then you can do this:

```r
index <- seq_along(x[[1]])
names(index) <- names(x[[1]])
l <- lapply(index, function(i) matrix(vapply(x, `[[`, 0, i), ncol = 2))
```

But since your data are fundamentally rectangular, constructing and operating on a matrix is (I think) much more intuitive.